# Can Cloud Load Balancer talk directly to a FastCGI server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

Is it possible to have a Google Cloud Load Balancer talk directly to a FastCGI server (i.e. a server implementing the FastCGI interface, not an HTTP server)?

I can of course put an nginx reverse proxy in front of the FastCGI server but if it's possible to have the load balancer talk directly to the FastCGI server then I'd like to do that for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a Google Cloud Load Balancer talk directly to a
> FastCGI server

No, you would need to configure a server that responds to HTTP requests (or TCP/SSL for some load balancers).

The FastCGI interface is a binary protocol interface for web servers such as Apache and Nginx.

Google load balancers do not support loading modules.